# want to map a json object unto a java object

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I am using a certain API which have a json output as below. I have parsed it to `String`.
the json output as string: `{"result":{"number":"INC0022500"}}`.

As you can see it has nested object for key `result`.

my snippet which i am using to map the above json unto a object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
EspIncidentTrial staff = gson.fromJson(json, EspIncidentTrial.class);
```

ESPIncidentTrial class:

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@Embeddable
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EspIncidentTrial {
    @JsonProperty("result")
    private ResultTrial result;

    public ResultTrial getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ResultTrial result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

For the nested object i created another class `ResultTrial`. Below is the body.

ResultTrial class:

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@Embeddable
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResultTrial {
    @JsonProperty("number")
    private String incidentId;

    public String getIncidentId() {
        return incidentId;
    }

    public void setIncidentId(String incidentId) {
        this.incidentId = incidentId;
    }
}
```

What happens now is, in `EspIncidentTrial` class, object `result` is getting mapped. However, inside `ResultTrial` class, no mapping is being done.

I tried treating the key `result` in the json object as String, but the threw the below error, which was expected though.

```
The error occured while parsing the JSON. com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 12 path $.result
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are mixing `gson` and `Jackson`.
You are using annoations of `Jackson`, but using `GSON's` method to deserailze it.

Use `Jackson's` `objectMapper` to deserialize.

E.g.:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
EspIncidentTrial staff = mapper.readValue(json, EspIncidentTrial.class);
```

Comment: Got the problem. Here is what happens when we try to fix some already written code. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this....

String searchdata="{\"userPojo\":{\"userid\":1156}}";

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(searchdata);

SummaryPojo summaryPojo=new SummaryPojo();

if(searchdata.contains("userPojo"))

{

String jsonstring=jsonObject.getString("userPojo");

Gson gson = new Gson();

UserPojo userPojo = gson.fromJson(searchdata, UserPojo.class);

summaryPojo.setUserPojo(userPojo);

}